# iOS App crashes with message "-[UITapGestureRecognizer setFrame:]" when adding Gesture in XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

My app crashes when adding Gesture to Custom View (XIB). I am using Xcode version 6.4.

Below are the steps I followed to add a custom subview with tap gesture:

1. Added an XIB and a UIView subclass (MyView) to my project. And set the XIB class to MyView.
2. Added a TapGesture to MyView using Interface Builder
3. Created MyView object (myView) and added it as a sub view using `[addSubview:myView]`.
4. When I run the app, it crashes
5. Removed the TapGesture in XIB and run again with no issues.

**Code:**

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
```

**Log:**

-[UITapGestureRecognizer setFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f924a4ce910

Sometimes like this,

-[UITapGestureRecognizer superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f924a4ce910

Please advice.

Comment: do you have some code in awakeFromNib or drawRect of your MyView implementation class. it seems like you are trying to set frame on TapGesture.

Comment: Yes awakeFromNib is there. But not setting any frames there.

Comment: you can try to add you tapgesture in awakeFromNib of you MyView. just to check if something going  wrong  in xib.

Comment: It works when adding gesture using code. But I wanted to know what is wrong with my code/xib.

Comment: @pawan: thanx for your advice. I have solved the issue by adding some extra line of code. I will add answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by replacing the code,

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
```

with

```
MyView *myView = nil;
NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil];
for (id object in objects)
{
  if ([object isKindOfClass:[MyView class]])
  {
    myView = object;
  }
}
```

**Note:**

If the XIB have a single `UIView` object only, then the single line code mentioned above is enough. But if the XIB have multiple `UIView` objects or any Gestures added in XIB, then we need to find out the `MyView` object from the array returned by the `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` method.